# Convert rails select_date to int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, select

I have two `date_selects` that I need to submit in a form as integers. I am under the impression that my solution is overcomplicated.

the problem:

```
<%= f.date_select :month_num, :discard_year => 'true', :discard_day => 'true', :use_month_numbers => 'true', :prompt => {:month => "Select month"} %>

<%= f.date_select :year_num, :order => [:year], :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year + 5, :prompt => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Neither of these methods above submit as integers.

To remedy this I can simply do the following:

```
<%= f.select :month_num, options_for_select([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]]) %>

<%= f.select :year_num, options_for_select([[Time.now.year], [Time.now.year + 1], [Time.now.year + 2], [Time.now.year + 3], [Time.now.year + 4], [Time.now.year + 5]]) %>
```

But this is ugly, there has to be a cleaner approach.

Am I able to submit these as ints using my original method?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, date_select will always supply the values as dates. If you want to simplify your remedy's syntax, you can use a view helper to generate the option values, for example,

```
<%= f.select :month_num, options_for_select(get_month_ints) %>
```

and in app/helpers/my_view_helper.rb

```
module MyViewHelper
  def get_month_ints
    [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]]
  end
end
```